# Rxjs6 - filter array of objects

Tags: rxjs

I would filter array of objects using RXJS operator `filter`

I've array of objects like this single one:

```
    {
      id: string,
      count: number
    }
```

I would get objects which `count > 20`

I tried:

```
  getVotes2(): Observable<Vote> {
    return this._http.get<Vote>(url)
     .pipe(
       map( results => results ),
       filter( result => result.count>20 )
     );
  }
```

next, without `map` and I always get all records.

Any ideas?

**---------CORRECT CODE------------**

```
getVotes2(): Observable<Vote[]> {
 return this._http.get<Vote[]>(url)
  .pipe(
    map( results => results.filter( r => r.count < 20) )
  )
}
```

Comment: Did you wanted to use `switchMap` instead of map here ?

Comment: I don't know how it exactly works. I need to filter array.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're confused on the use of the rx filter operator.

The filter rx operator is NOT the same as the array filter operator.  The rx filter operates on a stream and excludes things from THE STREAM that meet a condition, the array filter operator operates on an array and removes items from an array based on a condition.

What you're currently doing is filtering the stream on some undefined "count" property of the array itself, so you're saying "if undefined > 20, then don't let the item through the stream", and one of the quirks of javascript, undefined is not greater than 20 despite being an invalid comparison.

What you need to do is this:

```
getVotes2(): Observable<Vote[]> {
 return this._http.get<Vote[]>(url)
  .pipe(
    map( results => results.filter(r => r.count > 20) )
  );
}
```

This way, you use rx Map to perform an operation on the item IN the stream and use the array filter on the item to filter the array.

Edit: as pointed out, the typing also needs to be correct to let typescript know that you're expecting an array of vote objects rather than a single vote object.

Comment: I add type of array <Vote[]> and it's good result.
Thanks for explanation!

Comment: ah yea, good point, the typing needs to be correct, will update my answer

Comment: Just a small add-on (for future readers): both undefined > 20 AND undefined < 20 are  always false

Answer (score 0):

If http response you are getting is something like

```
{ 
  data: {
    results: [ {id: 'dd5144s', count: 14}, {id: 'dd51s4s', count: 22}, {id: 'dd5sa44s', count: 8}  ]
  }
}
```

Then try this:

```
 return this._http.get<Vote>(url)
   .pipe(
     switchMap( results => results ),
     filter( result => result.count>20 )
   );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Http  return me an array of objects which I would filter.

Comment: Editor show me an error: 'Type Observable<{}> is not assignable to type Observable<Vote>. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Vote'. Property 'count' is missing in type '{}''